# Labeling Points on a Plot

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have the following discrete map:
\begin{equation}
x_{n+1}=μ-x^4
\end{equation}
for which I have used manipulate to see the way the system evolves depending on the real parameter $μ$:

```
Manipulate[
 ListLinePlot[
  NestList[μ - #^4 &, x0, 100],
  PlotRange -> {0, 1},
  ImageSize -> {450, 375}],
 {{μ, 0.8, "parameter μ"}, 0, 4, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{x0, 0.2, "Initial \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(0\)]\)"},
  0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

What I would like to do is to show in some way the coordinates on the plot, so that one can see the values of $x$ for which a cycle 2 is defined, a cycle 4 is defined, a cycle 8 and so on. If that is not possible, how could I for example print below the plot, the last 16 coordinates of the 100th iteration in this particular map? *(so that one can see the recurrence of the 2,4,8,... points)*.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to show all 101 coordinates on the plot, or just a select few?  Would you be happy if it showed the coordinates for the points when the mouse hovers over them?

Comment: I would like in particular to always show the last 16 coordinates on the plot. That would do it. Even better if I could somehow extract them and print them below the graph

Comment: You are probably aware, but for $\mu$ larger than some value, the calculation aborts in an Overflow error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add a `TableForm` below the plot and combine them via `Column`

```
Manipulate[Module[{list = NestList[μ - #^4 &, x0, 100]},
  list2 = list;
  Column[{ListLinePlot[
     list,
     PlotRange -> {0, 1},
     ImageSize -> {450, 375}],
    TableForm[Transpose@{Range[86, 101], list[[-16 ;;]]},
     TableHeadings -> {None, {"point", "x"}}]}]
  ],
 {{μ, 0.8, "parameter μ"}, 0, 4, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{x0, 0.2, "Initial \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(0\)]\)"},
  0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! One last question, I can see that the points differ by 0.000013 as pairs. My guess is  that this happens due to compiling of some error?

Comment: I'm not sure I see what you mean, which points (by number) differ by that amount?  Also, another way to get this list would be to use `RecurrenceTable[{x[n + 1] == .8 - x[n]^4, x[1] == 0.2}, x, {n, 1, 
  101}]`

Comment: Ok, my bad, I did not see clearly the decimal digits above. Again thank you very much for your help, I appreciate it.